# Prevent using B or b from jumping to previous line in vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I found the following code on SO and it works great for using E to jump to words and stopping at the end of the line like this: `nnoremap <expr> E getline('.')[col('.') - 1:] =~# '\s\S' ? 'E' : (col('.') + 1 == col('g_') ? 'E' : '$')`.
But I only recently started dabbing into vimscripts and can't get it to work for going backwards with b/B.
I attempted to do something like this but didn't work as it doesn't stop at the start of the line:

```
nnoremap <expr> B getline('.')[col('.') + 1:] =~# '\S\s' ? 'B' : (col('.') - 1 == col('^') ? 'B' : '^')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
nnoremap <expr> B strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1) =~ '^\s*$' ? '0' : 'B'
```

`strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1)` picks up the substring left to the current cursor position. If this is empty or consists only of whitespaces (i.e., when `B` would normally jump to the previous line), then `B` is mapped to `0`, i.e., it goes to the first character of the line without jumping to the previous line. Otherwise, `B` behaves like the original `B`.